# Find Nearest Member by Latitude and Longitude West of a Point and East of a Point MySQL

Tags: mysql, coordinates

I'd like to make a swipe event that would take users to the nearest member from the one currently being viewed. Using the following code, I can find the nearest member but I don't know how to make it directional so that it doesn't just keep bouncing back and forth from profile A to profile B and back to A.

```
$sf = 3.14159 / 180; // scaling factor
$er = 6350; // earth radius in miles, approximate
$mr = 100; // max radius
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE $mr >= $er * ACOS(SIN(lat*$sf)*SIN($lat*$sf) + COS(lat*$sf)*COS($lat*$sf)*COS((lon-$lon)*$sf))
ORDER BY ACOS(SIN(lat*$sf)*SIN($lat*$sf) + COS(lat*$sf)*COS($lat*$sf)*COS((lon-$lon)*$sf))";
```

I thought simply adding `&& lon > $lon` to one swipe's query and `&& lon < $lon` might be the best solution... but by doing that it will keep walking farther and farther west/east and missing a lot of the people.

Comment: You can store the list of ids you visited and exclude them from your list (where ... and not id in (....)`. I would randomly allow to revisit some members, as it feels more natural. Also, there is a difference between jumping to the n'th closest unvisited member from your members location and to jump to the closest unvisited member of the n'th closest member. You seem to do the second way, if you would do it the first way, you could just use the first result you get (a list of n close members) and jump throught them one by one (but it is, as noted, something different than you currently do).

Comment: Thanks @Solarflare... that's actually what I ended up doing last night. It works for a one directional swipe as there is no way I can think of off-hand to reverse it. I think I'll just stick with this and they can swipe right to go to the next closest member and swiping left will do nothing. I might make the back button on phones take you to the last ID in the list... but I'm not even sure if that is just an Android thing. Do iPhones have a back button?